# Faster conversion to and from ctypes objects using buffers?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm converting lists of floats to ctypes `Structure` classes with the following fields, before passing them to an FFI function:

```
FFIArray(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("data", c_void_p),
                ("len", c_size_t)]

    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, seq):
        return seq if isinstance(seq, cls) else cls(seq)

    def __init__(self, seq, data_type = c_float):
        array_type = data_type * len(seq)
        raw_seq = array_type(*seq)
        self.data = cast(raw_seq, c_void_p)
        self.len = len(seq)
```

The returned FFIArray objects (always of the same length as the input, and the input values themselves aren't being modified by the FFI function) are being converted into lists of tuples like so:

```
class FFITuple(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", c_uint32),
                ("b", c_uint32)]

def void_array_to_tuple_list(array, _func, _args):
    # this is the errcheck function
    res = cast(array.data, POINTER(FFITuple * array.len))[0]
    res_list = [(i.a, i.b) for i in iter(res)]
    drop_bng_array(array)
    return res_list
```

This works perfectly, but the conversion steps on `__init__` and `errcheck` are still extremely slow for large lists. Is there any speed advantage to first converting the lists to objects which implement the buffer protocol, and creating the `FFIArray` objects from those using ctypes `from_buffer` (or `from_buffer_copy`, or maybe even `memmove`?), and then performing the reverse on the returned `FFIArray` objects?

Comment: You can do some minor optimizing to replace `cast` operations with `from_buffer`, but most likely the time is being spent in `array_type(*seq)` and `[(i.a, i.b) for i in iter(res)]`. For `seq`, can you switch to using something that supports the buffer protocol such as an `array.array('f')`? Is creating a list of tuples important for the output? If not, you can copy the array using `from_buffer_copy`.

Comment: @eryksun avoiding the tuple creation and converting to array.array first results in ~85% speedup when converting two million-item lists. I know it's not order-of-magnitude, but it's not minor, either. I didn't find (m)any SO questions (or answers) addressing the best way to do this in general – want to leave your advice as an answer with some general best practice for efficiently getting larger structures into ctypes?

Comment: Please add an answer. I'll provide feedback if I see other ways to improve the code.

Comment: In general with large data structures, try to avoid iterating in bytecode (e.g. list comprehensions), repeated conversions between Python and machine data types, and unnecessary copying. Using numpy may help with operating efficiently on machine data types, especially if it can work in parallel on multiple cores. ctypes also works well with multiprocessing, using shared memory/files and a process pool to distribute the workload.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks, done.

Answer (score 2):

Converting the list to an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) and using [`from_buffer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData.from_buffer) resulted in a 47.5% decrease in object creation time (test script now runs in 204ms vs 387ms, for a million-item list):

```
FFIArray(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("data", c_void_p),
                ("len", c_size_t)]

    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, seq):
        return seq if isinstance(seq, cls) else cls(seq)

    def __init__(self, seq, data_type = c_float):
        array_type = data_type * len(seq)
        try:
            raw_seq = array_type.from_buffer(seq.astype(np.float32))
        except (TypeError, AttributeError):
            try:
                raw_eq = array_type.from_buffer_copy(seq.astype(np.float32))
            except (TypeError, AttributeError):
                raw_seq = array_type.from_buffer(array('f', seq))
        self.data = cast(raw_seq, c_void_p)
        self.len = len(seq)
```

In addition, modifying the FFI function to return two sequences, and not explicitly combining them into tuples, led to a large speedup:

```
class ResTuple(Structure):
    """ Container for returned FFI data """
    _fields_ = [("e", FFIArray),
                ("n", FFIArray)]


def void_arrays_to_lists(restuple, _func, _args):
    """ Convert the lon, lat --> BNG FFI result to Python data structures """
    eastings = POINTER(c_uint32 * restuple.e.len).from_buffer_copy(restuple.e)[0]
    northings = POINTER(c_uint32 * restuple.n.len).from_buffer_copy(restuple.n)[0]
    res_list = [list(eastings), list(northings)]
    drop_bng_array(restuple.e, restuple.n)
    return res_list
```

We then modify our setup slightly with the new classes:

```
convert_bng = lib.convert_to_bng_threaded
convert_bng.argtypes = (FFIArray, FFIArray)
convert_bng.restype = ResTuple
convert_bng.errcheck = void_arrays_to_lists
# cleanup
drop_bng_array = lib.drop_int_array
drop_bng_array.argtypes = (FFIArray, FFIArray)
drop_bng_array.restype = None
```

---

### Test Script

```
import _BNG_FFIArray
import pyproj
import numpy as np

N = 55.811741
E = 1.768960
S = 49.871159
W = -6.379880

bng = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:27700')
wgs84 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')
num_coords = 1000000


def test_speed(lon_ls):
    lon_obj = _BNG_FFIArray(lon_ls)


lons = list(np.random.uniform(W, E, [num_coords]))
res = test_speed(lons)
```

Comment: If your data is originally in a numpy array, you may as well pass that to `from_buffer`. Otherwise, can you use an `array.array` from the start instead of a list? It's a nice middle ground because it's dynamic like a list, but works on machine data types to allow a quick 'cast' to a ctypes array using `from_buffer`.

Comment: Did you decide to continue creating the list of tuples instead of copying the array? The latter can be done using `res_array = POINTER(FFITuple * array.len).from_buffer_copy(array)[0]`.

Comment: @eryksun No, I switched to copying the array, which gave a big speedup (just trying to figure out a sensible way to measure it). In theory, I could start out with `array.array`, but the module is intended for end users, and most of them will pass lists or numpy arrays. I can make the `init` a bit more flexible by checking whether `seq` is an instance of list or tuple (not best practice, I know), and doing `from_buffer(seq.data)` if it isn't, since that means it's probably a numpy array.

Comment: Instead of checking types explicitly, you can use nested exception handling. If `array_type.from_buffer(seq)` raises a `TypeError`, try `array_type.from_buffer_copy(seq)` in case the buffer isn't writable. If that also raises a `TypeError`,  use `array_type.from_buffer(array('f', seq))`, which is faster than `array_type(*seq)` because the 'f' format initialization of `array.array` is specialized, while ctypes array initialization is more generic.